# Solve for rotation quaternion that rotates $x$ into $y$.

Tags: rotations, quaternions

Given two quaternions $x$ and $y$ with $|x|=|y|$, their real part being zero (i.e. them being vectors) and knowing that $y$ resulted from a rotation of $x$ by unit quaternion $q$, i.e.
$$ y = q x q^{-1}, $$
is it possible to solve for $q$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

I tried several kinds of multiplying from the left and from the right with $q$s, but non-commutative equation solving is rather unfamiliar and I cannot get the $q$ separated from both, $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Think about the analogous situation in $\mathbb R^3$: is there a unique rotation that maps a vector $x$ onto another vector $y$ with the same norm?

Comment: You mean I need to add that $|x|=|y|$ to get this working at all. Alright.

Comment: My main point is that there’s an infinite number of rotations that map $x$ onto $y$.

Comment: I believe you also need $x$ and $y$ to be "pure" quaternions, meaning real part zero. Such things are also called "vectors."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: @amd I can imagine two, along the short and along the long angle. Why infinite?

Comment: @WillJagy agreed, adding this to the question.

Comment: For every vector in the plane that bisects the angle between $x$ and $y$, there is a rotation about that axis that maps $x$ onto $y$.

Comment: @amd OK, do I misunderstand rotation then? For me a rotation would be the sweep through this plane, i.e. the rotation axis would always be orthogonal to the two vectors.

Comment: That’s only one out of the many possibilities. Another simple one to visualize is to pivot 180° about the bisector $\frac12(x+y)$. If you restrict yourself to the plane defined by $x$ and $y$, however, then there are only two possibilities, and you can always choose one for which the rotation angle lies in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: If you add the restriction that the rotation take place in the plane defined by $x$ and $y$, looking at the relationship between the quaternion product of two pure quaternions and the dot and cross products of the corresponding vectors might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an infinite number of rotations that map a vector $\vec x$ onto another vector $\vec y$ with the same norm, one for every vector that lies on the angle bisector of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. If we restrict them to the plane defined by $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, i.e., to an axis that’s perpendicular to both vectors, then in most cases there are only two possibilities, and we can always choose the one with rotation angle in the interval $[0,\pi]$.

It’s convenient for the following to represent quaternions as ordered pairs $(r,\vec v)$ of a real number $r$ and vector $\vec v$. The product of two quaternions is then $$(r_1,\vec v_1)(r_2,\vec v_2) = (r_1r_2-\vec v_1\cdot\vec v_2,r_1\vec v_2+r_2\vec v_1+\vec v_1\times\vec v_2).\tag 1$$ As you probably know, rotating the vector $\vec v$ through an angle of $\theta$ about the axis given by the unit vector $\vec u$ can be accomplished by conjugating the pure quaternion $\mathbf v = (0,\vec v)$ by $$\mathbf q = \left(\cos{\frac\theta2},\vec u\sin{\frac\theta2}\right).\tag 2$$ Now, for a pair of pure quaternions, the product (1) reduces to $$(0,\vec x)(0,\vec y) = (-\vec x\cdot\vec y,\vec x\times\vec y) = \|\vec x\|\|\vec y\|(-\cos\theta,\vec u\sin\theta),$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ and $\vec u = {\vec x\times\vec y\over\|\vec x\|\|\vec y\|}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec x\times\vec y$. Comparing this to (2), we can see that constructing an appropriate rotation quaternion $\mathbf q$ from $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ is reduced to constructing a pair of vectors in the plane of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ such that the angle between them is $\theta/2$. Taking $\vec x$ or $\vec y$ and their angle bisector $\vec x+\vec y$ will do the trick, resulting in $$\mathbf q = -\left(0,{\vec x+\vec y \over \|\vec x+\vec y\|}\right)\left(0,{\vec x \over \|\vec x\|}\right).$$ Note that this method fails when $\vec x=-\vec y$. In this case, $\mathbf q=(0,\vec u)$, where $\vec u$ is any unit vector orthogonal to $\vec x$.

Comment: Many thanks for the details. If I am not messing up, it turns out to be: if $\vec s= \vec x+ \vec y$ and for any vector $\vec v$ we say $\vec{v}_e = \vec v/\|\vec v\|$ then $q$ would be just $q=(\vec x_e\cdot \vec s_e, \vec x_e \times \vec s_e)$. Nice.

Comment: @Harald Looks right to me. I should’ve taken the computation that one extra step myself. It’s even easier to remember.